# Setup Stream capability in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, streaming

I'm taking a look at a Firebase library for .NET:

https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC site that I'm using to read/write data to Firebase. It's working great, but I'd like to incorporate the streaming listener functionality so I can get notified when data has changed.

What do I need to do in order to engage that? I don't believe it can just hang off an action method and be notified, correct?

```
EventStreamResponse response = await _client.OnAsync("chat", (sender, args) => {
       System.Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
});

//Call dispose to stop listening for events
response.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out for the most part.

In the Global.asax I have a method like below that I just call on App Start. Strange thing I'm not currently sure why is on initial load it calls the "added" method for all elements in the list.

```
    private static async void EventStreaming()
    {
        EventStreamResponse response = await FirebaseHelper.Client.OnAsync("emails",

        added: (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ADDED " + args.Data + " -> 2\n");
        },
        changed: (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CHANGED " + args.Data);
        },
        removed: (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("REMOVED " + args.Path);
        });

        //Call dispose to stop listening for events
        //response.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with https://www.nuget.org/packages/FirebaseSharp/ it's a good firebase .Net Client